# php bootstrap datatable server

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I am using a bootstrap datatable in my application.  I am using server side using ajax to fetch values from mysql database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url :"employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
            type: "post",  // method  , by default get
            error: function(){  // error handling
            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
            $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><thcolspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

        }
    }
} );
```

In employee-grid-data.php

```
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $row["employee_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["employee_salary"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["employee_age"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
    "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
    "data"            => $data   // total data array
);

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

So what I am looking for is - I want to add separate class for each tr row.  In the datatable I can't see any tr.  So how can I add a class to tr. (Different background color for tr based on condition).

Answer (score 0):

This [datatables example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) might help you, it does something very similar to what you want to accomplish.

It uses the `createdRow` init option to define a function that is called once for each row added (by ajax or any other source) to the datatable. In this function you can apply your logic to add a class to any rows that match your condition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            if ( data[5].replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 > 150000 ) {
                $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

(code taken from datatables docs)